# Why is this MVC route not working (ASP.Net Core 2.2)

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have the following API Controller in my ASP.Net Core project:

```
[Authorize]
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
[ApiController]
public class PermissionsController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly PlanraumContext _context;

    public PermissionsController(PlanraumContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    [HttpGet("api/[controller]/group/[action]")]
    public ActionResult Get(int folderId)
    {
        return Ok(new PermissionHelper(_context).GetGroupPermissions(folderId));
    }
}
```

Unfortunately I cannot access my function "Get". I tried the following paths

- api/permissions/group/get?folderId=6811
- api/permissions/group/get
- api/permissions/get?folderId=6811

And all of them return a 404 error.

Is there anything wrong with my routing? I didn't configure anything specific in my startup.cs

```
app.UseMvc(routes =>
{
    routes.MapRoute(
              name: "default",
              template: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
});
```

Comment: I would start by removing the parameter at the `HttpGet` attribute, you probably failing on mismatch of routings. Change to `[HttpGet]`

Comment: You are mixing attribute and conventional [routing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're placing route for action in the controller 
Kindly do it this way

On controller level

```
[Authorize]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
```

On action level

```
[HttpGet("group/[action]/{folderId}")]
```

and if you don't need group than simply do

```
[HttpGet("[action]/{folderId}")]
```

Answer (score 4):

In your code the `url` will be [combination](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-2.2#combining-routes) of what you have defined on `controller` level and `action` level.

> Route templates applied to an action that begin with / or ~/ don't get combined with route templates applied to the controller.

You can define `[Route("/api/[controller]/group/[action]")]` on `action` which will ignore `controller` level route.

```
[Authorize]
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
[ApiController]
public class PermissionsController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly PlanraumContext _context;

    public PermissionsController(PlanraumContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    [Route("/api/[controller]/group/[action]")]
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Get(int folderId)
    {
        return Ok(new PermissionHelper(_context).GetGroupPermissions(folderId));
    }
}
```